# Como instalar o JavaFX?

Tags: java, linux, javafx, jdk

Sou usuario de Linux (Fedora Workstation 26) e eu estou tentando desenvolver uma aplicação em JavaFX usando o Netbeans como IDE, o problema é que eu não achei o download do SDK do JavaFX para linux, e o link oficial do download na página da Oracle foi desativado porque diz que eo JavaFX foi implementado nos últimos JDKs e JREs.

Gostaria de saber a partir de qual a versão do JDK e JRE já vem com JavaFX?

Comment: JavaFx2 já é integrante do JDK 7, se você o instalou, já estaria apto a programar nessa API. Agora se quiser alguma facilidade para construir telas, precisa de algum builder de telas.

Comment: Na documentação diz que a partir do JDK 7u6 o JavaFX já seria incluso.

Answer (score 1):

No JDK 7 ele já vem incluso, sem necessidade de API externa, se você quer começar utilize os exemplos no site da Oracle.
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm

Answer (score 1):

O javafx está incluso no jdk7, porém ele não está no classpath. Para utilizá-lo você precisa adicionar a biblioteca manualmente no seu projeto.

A partir do jdk8, o javafx já está configurado no classpath.

Contudo, não sei se em todas as distros do linux acontece o mesmo, mas no ubuntu, apenas instalar o openjdk não é suficiente. É necessário instalar também o openjfx.